# regex match in PHP

Tags: php, regex

I’m trying to perform a regex match in PHP and I wonder how to do it correctly.

I looked into `preg_match` and things but it looks very confusing for a newbie like me.

I know that in [AHK (AutoHotKey)](http://www.autohotkey.com) I can use this command:

```
regexmatch(var, "<td style=""""><a.*?>(.*?)</", out)
```

And `var` is:

```
<td style=""><a href="/player/33598934">tofind</a></td>
```

and then variable `out1` would be:

```
tofind
```

But how can I achieve this in PHP?

Comment: What exactly looks confusing to you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documention](http://www.php.net//manual/en/function.preg-match.php) states clearly how to use [`preg_match()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php), it briefly explains these parameters.

```
preg_match ( string $pattern , string $subject [, array &$matches [, int $flags = 0 [, int $offset = 0 ]]] )
```

Only difference is you would need to use different [**delimiters**](http://www.php.net//manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php), and reduce the double quotes in your regex.

```
preg_match('~<td style=""><a.*?>(.*?)</~', $str, $match);
echo $match[1]; //=> "tofind"
```

**Note**: Here we use `$match[1]` to access what was matched in capturing group `#1`

---

It is alot easier and preferred to use a [**Parser**](http://www.php.net//manual/en/book.dom.php) instead when it comes to parsing HTML.

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($html); // Load your HTML data

$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$node  = $xpath->query("//td//a");

echo $node->item(0)->nodeValue;
```

[**Working Demo**](https://eval.in/165653)

Comment: very interesting! this explains it very well,i will try it immdeatly

Comment: amazing,works like a charm! i will chance my regex commands a bit and i will succeed ! thanks mate

Answer (score 0):

use this:

```
preg_match('_<td style=""><a href="/player/33598934">(\w*)</a></td>_','<td style=""><a href="/player/33598934">tofind</a></td>',$out);

echo $out[1];
```